# Duplicate answers where the higher quality answer was added after the lower quality answer

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

Following on [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2080/440) question, what should the policy be if an existing question with an existing answer gets a new answer that is higher quality (e.g. provides a source, maybe adds additional information, but leaves the original answer with nothing new or distinct about it)?

Should the new content be merged into the old answer? Should the old answer be deleted in favor of the new one? תיקו (let it stand)?

Comment: I figure Eliayhu and the Mashiach will have better things to do than go through Jewish message boards answering questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not uncommon for this to happen. The initial course of action is obvious, up-vote the new (and better) post. Folks can readily see that it is newer, unless it's buried on a second page of answers. If *that* happens, then you're probably going to need to look at why the question got so many answers to begin with. It's not always a bad sign, but it's worth examining.

I wouldn't *delete* existing answers unless they were no longer relevant *and* offered information that could now be considered misleading or even dangerous. If they're still relevant, just leave them, they represent the time someone put into contributing to the site and it's a shame to discard that unless you're solving a more immediate problem.

Chat is a *great* facility to use in order to draw attention to new contributions that should by rights rise to the top. Don't down vote the old one *just* because it now compares unfavorably with the new one, that doesn't make the old answer bad, but simply the new one better.

Over time, this tends to sort itself out pretty well, even on some of our higher traffic sites; don't worry about it *too* much.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the answer to this question, it seems to me that it should result ultimately in the same situation as the [other question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2080/440). That is the order of events should not ultimately be the driver of different site content.