# Should I delete my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, deletions

I recently answered a question, and as I posted the answer I realised someone else had "beat me to the punch" and had posted (almost exactly) the same answer as I was wording mine.

What's the rule / proper etiquette here? Should I delete my answer (especially because it's no longer needed)? Or should I leave it there and let people see both?

Comment: In the time since I had previously looked at the post in question and now (around 10 minutes later) the other answer was deleted, either by a mod or the OP. However, it would be good to know the answer anyway

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2080/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah. Or at least it answers my question